# Setting values in nested class fields using parent class constructor initialization list

Tags: c++, class, constructor, nested, parent

Is there a way to make a constructor initialization list, which sets values for a nested class fields?
E.g.:

.h

```
    class A {
    public:
         A(int tmp);
         class B{
           friend A;
           int x;
         };
         B b;
    }
```

.cpp

```
    A(int tmp): x(tmp){};
```

How to correctly do that using constructor initialization list? If that's possible.

EDIT: Mistake in the example.

Comment: An `A` does not contain a `B`. If you want to do that, you have to add a member variable of type `B` to `A`, and initialize that.

Comment: Do you have a member of `B` in `A`?  If not why are you trying to instantiate it?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. Fixed the code. There is B object in class A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You can use the member initialization list of `A` to initialize `b`.  Normally you would call an appropriate `B` constructor, but in this case, `B` doesn't actually have any constructors declared, but is simple enough that standard aggregate initialization will work.

```
class A {
public:
    A(int tmp);
    class B{
    public:
        friend A;
        int x;
    };
    B b;
};

A::A(int tmp) : b{tmp} {}
```

Note: I had to make the member of `B` public.  If you don't want to do that, you will need to declare a constructor.

Comment: I don't really get the idea here. How does `A::A(int tmp) : b{tmp} {}` set the value to the x? What happens if there is also another field `int y`?

Comment: It's just the same as if you write `struct B { int x, int y } b = {1};` .  `b.x` is the first member, and will be initialized to 1.  `b.y` will be zero-initialized.  Remember the *only* difference between `struct` and `class` in C++ is the default access for members and bases; nothing else.